# Image Brush Not working windows phone 8.1

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My  xaml  code

```
   <Grid Background="White">
    <StackPanel Height="580" Margin="0,0,0,50" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Height="70" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Height="50" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="imgProfile" Height="180" Width="180"  Visibility="Visible"  >
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/IOB Wallet/Images/Profile/photo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Height="40" Text="Welcome Back !!!" Foreground="#06419D" FontSize="30" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4"/>
        <TextBlock Height="40" Text="" Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4"/>
        <TextBlock Height="30" Text="" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Normal" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="If you are Not ?" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="75,10,0,0"/>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Change User" Foreground="#06419D" FontSize="20" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <PasswordBox Height="40" PlaceholderText=" Password"  BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#06419D" Margin="4,0,2,0"/>
        <HyperlinkButton Foreground="#06419D" FontWeight="Light" Visibility="Visible" Content="Forgot Your Password ?" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="234" />

    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="LOGIN" Name="btnGetstarted" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,-8" BorderThickness="0" Background="#06419D" Height="56" Width="500" Click="btnLogin_Click"  />
```

Image is  Visisble in Xaml  design view.After Running/deploying   application ,Image not  showing .  My photo Actual dimensions 100 * 100.. 
please Suggest  a  solution

Comment: try to setup full image path:
ms-appx:///Assets/IOB Wallet/Images/Profile/photo.png or ms-appx:///IOB Wallet/Images/Profile/photo.png

I don't know where is your image

Comment: Tried it.Not  working..

Comment: try    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/IOB Wallet/Images/Profile/photo.png"  />

Comment: Tried ..not  working

Answer (score 1):

```
<Ellipse x:Name="imgProfile" Height="180" Width="180"  Visibility="Visible"  >
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///IOB Wallet/Images/Profile/photo.png"  />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting background via Properties window. Click inside `Ellipse` tag in XAML code and press `F4` key to open Properties window. Expand Brush item and choose Tile Brush. Choose `ImageSource` via dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: Did you check "Build Action" value in properties?